# Is there a word to represent "non-Sunday" days?

Tags: grammar

We have a word like "weekday" to represent all days from Monday and Friday.

Is there a word to represent "non-Sunday" days (i.e. Monday through to Saturday)?

Comment: *Ordinary day*, *workaday*.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, *weekday* can still be used to mean any day other than Sunday. This usage has become less prevalent since much of the developed world moved to a five day workweek, so might need a note of explanation, but it is consistent with the traditional meaning of the word.

Comment: to the same effect can be considered businessday as well as workdays but it excludes saturday in modern times.